# Checking for odd integers causing errors in Java

Tags: java

I am a Java beginner. Here's my question:

The following method is supposed to determine if an int value passed as the argument, is an odd number:

```
public static boolean isOdd(int i) {
    return i % 2 == 1;
}
```

However, I am getting an error.
May I know what I am missing?

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: `return (i%2 == 1);`

Comment: @theguywhodreams The parentheses aren't necessary.

Comment: To the people who down-voted because they could not see an error ... you are wrong on two counts!

Comment: ... the problem you're (probably) seeing wouldn't be present if you first defined an `isEven(...)` method, then changed `isOdd(...)` to call that method and negated (Boolean operator `!`) the result.  Sometimes minor tweaks to algorithms can make things much more understandable and correct.

Comment: @StephenC the idea is that the OP highlights the error and what he expected to happen instead; not to leave everyone guessing whether he meant a compile error, a logical error, or something else.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt - In this case, I think that the OP has found this problem in an exam question or the like.  He has probably given all of the information that he knows.  See the word "purports"?  (It is only in the edit history now, 'cos some bright spark chose to edit it out ...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The operator `%` (with 2 as second argument) can also return -1. Thus, either use the absolute value of the argument, or - preferable - compare the absolute value of `i%2` with 1.

`Math.abs()` is available:

```
 public static boolean isOdd(int i) {
    return Math.abs(i % 2) == 1;
 }
```

Comment: Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3

Comment: Is it possible to correct this without using the API method?

Comment: @JianWu `i = (i < 0) ? -i : i;` should do the same thing? i.e. negate negative values, which is what `Math.abs` does. Or in one line, `return ((i < 0) ? -i : i) % 2 == 1;`

Comment: return i%2==1 || i%2==-1;    is this legal in java?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that this method is failing for negative numbers.

The following fails.

```
assertTrue(isOdd(-1));
```

The following code will pass the test.

```
return Math.abs(i % 2) == 1;
```